# Double and float VC++

Tags: visual-c++, double, fft

I am new to VC ++. I'm trying to compile the library FFT3W.

When I try to compile

```
// Define temporary buffers 
data_t fft_buffer; 
data_t zeros; 

// Allocate memory and initialize to 0 
fft_buffer.resize (2 * partition_size, 0.0f); 
zeros.resize (2 * partition_size, 0.0f); 

// Create plans for halfcomplex fft data format 
fftwf_plan fft_plan = 
fftw_plan_r2r_1d (2 * partition_size, & fft_buffer [0], 
& fft_buffer [0], FFTW_R2HC, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
```

I get the following error

```
Error C2664: 'fftw_plan_r2r_1d': can not convert parameter 2 from 'float *' to 'double *'
```

The function fftw_plan_r2r_1d is defined as:

```
fftw_plan_r2r_1d(int n, double *in, double *out, fftw_r2r_kind kind, unsigned flags);
```

Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: what the function `fftw_plan_r2r_1d` declaration is? we cannot guess what it does? also same goes for `data_t`

Comment: @DOOM fftw_plan_r2r_1d(int n, double *in, double *out, fftw_r2r_kind kind, unsigned flags);

Comment: `data_t` is apparently a buffer of `float`, which is not compatible with a buffer of `double`.

Comment: What @RaymondChen said. Since you're passing the address of the variable, it's important the variable is the size/type the function expects. If the float is 4 bytes in size, that would be a problem for the function if it's expecting a variable 8 bytes in size. The compiler is kind enough to tell you about the type mismatch. If it were just the variable's value (not its address,) you could likely get away passing the float as an argument value.

Comment: @RaymondChen yes, data_t is a buffer of float:

typedef std::vector<float> data_t;

Comment: As I can do the conversion in passing parameters? @bvj

Comment: The compiler can help with value conversion given the risk of losing precision, but it won't change the size of your declared variables. In other words, you need to pass the variable type declared by the function which in this case is a double, not a float; assuming the double 8 bytes, the float 4 bytes.

Comment: @bvj And how could I convert from float to double without changing the type data_t?

Comment: `vector<double> converted_data(fft_buffer.begin(), fft_buffer.end()); fftw_plan_r2r_1d(..., &converted_data.front(), ...);`

Comment: You should use the single precision FFTW library - it's the same API except each call has an extra `f`, so `fftw_plan_r2r_1d` is for doubles, `fftwf_plan_r2r_1d` is for floats.